# How to list all methods-of-a-class/classes that are not tested?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, moq, code-coverage

I want to have a list of not-tested methods/classes but not sure how to get it. Please help.

[Edit]
I'm using test framework Moq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after a code coverage program.

Which unit testing framework are you using? If you're using Microsoft's built in unit test framework in VS2010 Ultimate or Premium you'll have code coverage built in.  You can enable it by following [these steps](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/marcelv/archive/2009/05/22/how-to-enable-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2010-unit-tests.aspx).

If you don't have Ultimate/Premium, or you're using another framework (ie: NUnit), you could consider [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) from JetBrains.

For a free alternative, if you're using NUnit, you can [download the community edition](http://www.ncover.com/download/community) of NCover (a previously free coverage framework).

Answer (score 0):

Use something like NCover

See http://ncover.sourceforge.net/
and http://www.ncover.com/

This shows your a complete report of your unit test coverage and what classes are tested or not.